# Difference between kill <pid> and kill -s TERM <pid>

Tags: linux, shell, kill, signals

What exactly is the difference between `kill <pid>` and `kill -s TERM <pid>`.
Initially i thought the `$TERM` variable holds a signal number but when I echo TERM its gives me

```
$echo $TERM
xterm-256color
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no difference. From `man kill`:

> The default signal for kill is TERM.

```
kill -s TERM <pid>
```

**does not** expand the variable `TERM`, as `kill -s $TERM <pid>` would. It uses the string `TERM`.

The correspondence between signal numbers and names are in `man 7 signal`. Also, from the [POSIX specification of `kill`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/kill.html) (my italics),

> -s  signal_name
> Specify the signal to send, using one of the symbolic names defined in the <signal.h> header. *Values of signal_name shall be recognized in a case-independent fashion, without the SIG prefix*. In addition, the symbolic name 0 shall be recognized, representing the signal value zero. The corresponding signal shall be sent instead of SIGTERM.

Answer (score 4):

The `kill` from GNU coreutils (version 8.32 that I have installed) has a `--table` or `-L` option that outputs this information:

```
 1 HUP    Hangup: 1
 2 INT    Interrupt: 2
 3 QUIT   Quit: 3
 4 ILL    Illegal instruction: 4
 5 TRAP   Trace/BPT trap: 5
 6 ABRT   Abort trap: 6
 7 EMT    EMT trap: 7
 8 FPE    Floating point exception: 8
 9 KILL   Killed: 9
10 BUS    Bus error: 10
11 SEGV   Segmentation fault: 11
12 SYS    Bad system call: 12
13 PIPE   Broken pipe: 13
14 ALRM   Alarm clock: 14
15 TERM   Terminated: 15
16 URG    Urgent I/O condition: 16
17 STOP   Suspended (signal): 17
18 TSTP   Suspended: 18
19 CONT   Continued: 19
20 CHLD   Child exited: 20
21 TTIN   Stopped (tty input): 21
22 TTOU   Stopped (tty output): 22
23 IO     I/O possible: 23
24 XCPU   Cputime limit exceeded: 24
25 XFSZ   Filesize limit exceeded: 25
26 VTALRM Virtual timer expired: 26
27 PROF   Profiling timer expired: 27
28 WINCH  Window size changes: 28
29 INFO   Information request: 29
30 USR1   User defined signal 1: 30
31 USR2   User defined signal 2: 31
```

Comment: Does this signal number and corresponding function differs across machines...

Comment: @mohammedwazeem The POSIX defined signal numbers will be the more reliable to use on different Unix-like machines. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_(IPC)#POSIX_signals